# Precautionary security measures for a home user? (firewall, antivirus, etc)

Tags: security, firewall, ufw, antivirus, gufw

I just recently made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu, and I'm just a little paranoid when it comes to security measures.

I've looked around and from what I've read, security is not as big a concern as on a Windows OS, but I just want to make sure I'm somewhat covered.

Currently, I have installed ClamTK anti-virus and gufw (and enabled it once).

So basically I have three questions :

1. Aside from those apps, updating regularly, and downloading from trusted sources only, should I be taking any other precautions?
2. Must I do anything more with gufw other than checking enabled or are the default settings (incoming : deny, outgoing : allow) sufficient?
3. Do I have to manually turn on gufw everytime and enable it (and keep it open)? Everytime I open it the enabled checkbox is unchecked.

**EDIT:** When I open gufw, I must unlock and enter my password, however the checkbox is now checked. Must I always open gufw did I simply need to enable it once?

Thank you.

Comment: You're a typical paranoid ex-windows user :) installing anti-viruses and firewalls ... you don't really need that stuff in Ubuntu, as long as you are at least an averagely experienced. Great job on switching to Ubuntu, by the way, I'm sure later down the road you'll understand you don't really need those apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good questions.

> Aside from those apps, updating regularly, and downloading from trusted sources only, should I be taking any other precautions?

Not really.  Don't run random commands, especially those mentioning `sudo`, that people might give you on the web, unless it's a trustworthy source or you know what it does.

Beyond that I think the main thing you want to be careful with is web security, eg not typing your facebook password into random other web sites.

**Update** [rigved](https://askubuntu.com/users/13802/rigved) wisely suggests installing security-oriented browser plugins:  Adblock Plus, HTTPS Everywhere, Noscript and WOT.  (rigved also says Tor, but I'm not so sure about that, because Tor has major [security risks](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2007/09/anonymity_and_t_1.html) that make it a bad default for most people.)

**Update2** Do not use the WOT browser plugin, as it has serious privacy concerns: https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html . Thanks to [DJCrashdummy](https://askubuntu.com/users/354350/djcrashdummy) for pointing this out.

> Must I do anything more with gufw other than checking enabled or are the default settings (incoming : deny, outgoing : allow) sufficient?

That should be fine.

> Do I have to manually turn on gufw everytime and enable it (and keep it open)? Everytime I open it the enabled checkbox is unchecked.

It actually does stay enabled after you quit, but [bug 850468](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gui-ufw/+bug/850468) makes it looks like it's not enabled, until you authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Also I have a correction to make. After looking back at gufw, when I open it, it seems i must press unlock and enter my password, but the checkbox is now checked. Is this normal behaviour? And should I be keeping the application open, or can I close once it's enabled?

Comment: @Shane This is normal behaviour. You can close once enabled. Firewall will still work.

Comment: You need to enter your password to become root to modify the configuration.  You don't need to leave the app running: it is just a configuration tool and the actual firewall lives in the kernel, and is set up by a script at boot time.  You can verify this by running `sudo iptables -L` from a terminal.

Comment: OK, I see: the firewall is apparently off in gufw until you authenticate (although it's actually on all the time.)

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the answers. @poolie, I'd upvote too but I don't seem to have enough rep.

Comment: Also, in terms of Web sercurity, using the following extensions in Firefox helps: Adblock Plus, HTTPS Everywhere, Noscript, Tor and WOT

Comment: @rigve good suggestions, though I would question whether people should use Tor across the board: that has security tradeoffs (untrusted exits), as well as possibly causing functional problems.

Comment: @poolie, yes that is there. Just a suggestion to use Tor only when required and turn it off when not required.

Comment: Until I read the comments I wondered who the hell @rigved was. I was like "Is he some kind of security expert?" LOL!

Comment: @Ufoguy nope just a regular ubuntu user! :)

Comment: @rigved: do **NOT install WOT**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html